# How to write state changing routine, similar to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

How can I write a really super, simple state changing routine? I need something like Redux, but way simpler, don't need all the bells & whistles.

I was thinking of a global object i.e. `myState = {}`, that is changed via `setMyState() / getMyState()`.

I'm using JavaScript, and wondering if this would be done via a timer that polls say every 10ms, or so.

So in my JavaScript client app (I'm using ReactJS), a call to my `getMyState("show-menu")` inside a `render()` would update the Component's state just like using `this.state.`.

The reason I want this is:
1) Wanna know how to write it for learning purposes. 
2) Need something simpler that Redux, simple like Meteor's Session vars, so don't have to pass this.Refs. down to child compnents which setState on parent components. 
3) Redux is a mouthful, there is still lots to digest and learn to use Redux.

Comment: Would the browser history.state be too many bells and whistles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could do this pretty simply with a constructor.

```
function State () {
   this._state = {};
...
}

State.prototype.get = function () {
    return this._state;
};

State.prototype.set = function (state) {
    return this._state = state;
};

var STATE = new State();
```

But then you have to do the polling you mentioned in your post. Alternatively, you can look at eventEmitter libraries for javascript, for example https://github.com/facebook/emitter, and turn the State object into an event emitter.

Comment: Yes, I can use that to change state for components, such that when the mount they don't need any state updates. Emitter looks exactly like what I can use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, at all, but it's simpler.

```
function makeStore () {
  var state = { };
  return {
    set (key, value) { state[key] = value; },
    get (key) { return state[key]; }
  };
}


const store = makeStore();

store.set("counter", 1);
store.get("counter"); // 1
```

---

Believe it or not, there's really not a lot to Redux.
There's, perhaps, a lot to think about, and it's extra work to keep everything untied from your store...

But have a quick look:

```
function reducer (state, action) {
  state = state || { count: 0 };
  const direction = (action.type === "INCREASE") ? 1 : (action.type === "DECREASE") ? -1 : 0;
  return {
    count: (state.count + direction)
  };
}

function announceState () {
  console.log(store.getState());
}

function updateView () {
  const count = store.getState().count;
  document.querySelector("#Output").value = count || 0;

}
function increase () {
  store.dispatch({ type: "INCREASE" });
}
function decrease () {
  store.dispatch({ type: "DECREASE" });
}

const store = createStore(reducer, { count: 0 });
store.subscribe(announceState)
     .subscribe(updateView);

document.querySelector("#Increment").onclick = increase;
document.querySelector("#Decrement").onclick = decrease;
updateView();
```

This is the code I intend to use.
Looking at it, I'm pretty much just creating a store (with a function to run every time there's an event), there's the subscription to have a listener run, after the store has updated, there's a line where I fire an action, and...  ...well, that's it.

```js
function createStore (reduce, initialState) {
  var state = initialState;
  var listeners = [];

  function notifyAll () {
    listeners.forEach(update => update());
  }

  function dispatch (event) {
    const newState = reduce(state, event);
    state = newState;
    notifyAll();
    return store;
  }

  function subscribe (listener) {
    listeners.push(listener);
    return store;
  }

  function getState () {
    return state;
  }

  const store = {
    getState, subscribe, dispatch
  };

  return store;
}




// THIS IS MY APPLICATION CODE
function reducer (state, action) {
  state = state || { count: 0 };
  const direction = (action.type === "INCREASE") ? 1 : (action.type === "DECREASE") ? -1 : 0;
  return {
    count: (state.count + direction)
  };
}

function announceState () {
  console.log(store.getState());
}

function updateView () {
  const count = store.getState().count;
  document.querySelector("#Output").value = count || 0;
  
}
function increase () {
  store.dispatch({ type: "INCREASE" });
}
function decrease () {
  store.dispatch({ type: "DECREASE" });
}

const store = createStore(reducer, { count: 0 });
store.subscribe(announceState)
     .subscribe(updateView);

document.querySelector("#Increment").onclick = increase;
document.querySelector("#Decrement").onclick = decrease;
updateView();
```

```html
<button id="Decrement">-</button>
<output id="Output"></output>
<button id="Increment">+</button>
```

The very tiny, very easy implementation of a store (note that the real thing is more complex) is above. `dispatch` and `subscribe` are very useful, here.

Comment: That's way more code that say a `setMyState("counter", value)`. And then `count = getMyState("counter")`. Check out Session vars in Meteor. I'm aiming for super simple. No dispatch, reducer or store. Just a way to update state without relying on React's own built in `this.state`. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your code example btw.

Comment: @GiantElk the difference, though, between implementing Meteor, and implementing Redux, is that I've put most of Redux together at this point...  What features of Meteor are you actually looking for?

Comment: @GiantElk I get the session variables thing...  ...do you mean also writing the underlying subscribers, or writing the equality function, which offers an equality answer without triggering all of the subscribers? Or just getting and setting keys on an object? Because there's more black-magic that happens under the hood of Meteor than there is in Redux (because Meteor accomplishes many more things). That's kinda been my point. The code that you suggested was "Too big" was me being some error-handling and middleware supporting away from rewriting almost all of Redux.js, but not Meteor.

Comment: @GiantElk but as you saw, if you just want an object which gets and sets keys and values to a hidden store, you can do that in 4 lines of JS, if you want (or a 1-liner, if you don't want it to be that clean).